# What determines where the Packages folder is placed in a Visual Studio 2017 project & how to change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, nuget

What determines where the Packages folder is located in a VS2017 Solution/Project folder structure? 
With some solutions it seems to be located at the Solution level and with some of our projects it seems to be located within the project structure and is automatically being put into source control (which we don't want).

I need a way to force this project to put the packages folder outside the project folder.

Comment: I have found and just confirmed that when creating an ASP.Net MVC (foundation) project from the default templates in VS2017 the Packages folder is always created outside (one level lower than) the actual application's root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this reference on the Microsoft Docs site [Nuget Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)

> The location in which to install NuGet packages instead of **the default *$(Solutiondir)/packages* folder**.